# How to render component only client side with Remix?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, remix.run

I have a three.js component that should only be rendered client side, how do I do this with Remix? Does Remix expose any utilities to help determine if we're in a server or client context? Could not find anything.

Here is an example of what I'm attempting to do with fictional hooks that don't exist in remix.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRemixContext } from '@remix-run/react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const remixContext = useRemixContext();
  if(remixContext.server) {
     return null;
  }
  return <div>Should only be rendered on the client</div>
}
```

Comment: Check out `<ClientOnly>` from `remix-utils` https://github.com/sergiodxa/remix-utils#clientonly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can use the `ClientOnly` component exposed by the `remix-utils` library, which takes a function returning a component as a child which will be rendered client side only.

This component uses the hook `useHydrated` internally which is also exposed if you do not wish to use the component only for client side rendering.

Note that in development mode this did not originally work for me, I don't know if this is because I'm using remix-deno template or that it just does not work in general with the live reload, but once deployed in production it worked like a charm.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ClientOnly } from "remix-utils";

const App = () => {
  return <ClientOnly fallback={null}>
     {() => <MyComponent/>}
  </ClientOnly>
}
```

Also note that `Suspense` will eventually be [released](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/Suspense) which should replace the above code.

Answer (score 5):

The remix-utils does not support the latest version of remix, which is 2.x, now. I can solve it by using React Suspense and lazy function.

```
import type { MetaFunction } from "@remix-run/cloudflare";
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import "easymde/dist/easymde.min.css";

let SimpleMDE = lazy(async () => {
  const module = await import("react-simplemde-editor");

  return { default: module.default };
});
const MemoizedMDE = React.memo(SimpleMDE);

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Simple MDE</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <MemoizedMDE />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: nice solution...

Answer (score 0):

Great solution from Yoshiki Masubuchi . I have a slight variation on this, setting the Select in state. I was also struggling with remix-utils in Remix-v2 which  I was using it as [React-Select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) doesn't play well with Remix.

```
    import type { ComponentType } from 'react';
    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

    export const CurrencySelect = (): JSX.Element => {
      // react-select doesn't work on server https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3590 so we import dynamically
      const [Select, setReactSelectImported] = useState < ComponentType < any >> ();

      useEffect(() => {
        const loadReactSelectOnClient = async() => {
          const module = await import ('react-select');
          setReactSelectImported(module.default);
        };

        loadReactSelectOnClient();
      }, []);

      return Select ? < Select menuPlacement = "auto"
      isSearchable = {
        false
      }
      /> : <div>Loading...</div > ;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Great solutions. I have one more solution using `clientLoader` and `HydrateFallback`. I like this solution because it is very declarative, but the drawback is that is only works for an entire route.

You can make your component hydrate only on the client by defining a `clientLoader` and instructing the component to only hydrate after the `clientLoader` ran with `HydrateFallback`.

Here's a proof-of-concept:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export async function clientLoader() {
  return null;
}

export function HydrateFallback() {
  return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
}

export default function test() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(localStorage.getItem("test"));
  return <h1>I'm a client-side component {state}</h1>;
}
```

Note that this will take a second to re-hydrate on the client, and will show the fallback on load.

Source: https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/hydrate-fallback